# Water in vehicle tyres

Tags: tires, automotive-design, tractor

Why are some vehicles tires filled with water? What is the reason behind it. Is it done for all the vehicles or only heavy vehicles?

Comment: What examples have you found?

Comment: In tractors I have found them

Answer (score 4):

This is common practice in the agricultural industry ( I worked as a agricultural contract driver) as it is an easy and cheap way of adding weight to the tractor when needed.

It works as the relatively low rotating speed of the wheels ( tends to be the rear mostly) means the water stays in the bottom part of the wheel.

Edit: the extra weight can also be to help balance the tractor if you are using a front loader for example.

Comment: Why do we need to add weight to tractor

Comment: @user40021 to push through mud.

Comment: @user40021 - As Ben said, which also means more traction.

Comment: Instead of adding weight in the rear wheels can we add weight on the rear side of vehicle and produce same traction??

Comment: Yes, weight can be used - why do you think trailers have to be loaded so carefully...